# Show event is in a tail field

Tags: probability-theory

Given random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$, let $\tau = \bigcap_{n\geq1} \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, ...)$ be their tail field.

How do I show that $( \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty) \in \tau$?

What I tried:

$\exists a \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty) = (\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n+a} = \infty)$

Since $(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty) = (\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n+a} = \infty) \in \sigma (X_a, X_{a+1}, ...)$,

$(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty) = (\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n+a+1} = \infty) \in \sigma (X_{a+1}, X_{a+2}, ...)$ and so on,

$(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty) \in \bigcap_{n\geq a} \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, ...)$

Now I am stuck.

$\bigcap_{n\geq a} \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, ...) \subsetneq \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, ...)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already shown that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have

$$A:=\left\{ \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty \right\} \in \sigma(X_k,X_{k+1},\ldots).$$

Since this holds for *any* $k \in \mathbb{N}$, this yields

$$A \in \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \sigma(X_k,X_{k+1},\ldots) = \tau.$$

Comment: Thanks saz. So my "a" above holds for any $a \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: @BCLC Yes; $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = \infty$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n+a} = \infty$ for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$.